# iOS chromecast app connecting but not launching with new framework

Tags: ios, chromecast

Hello I am trying to cast the demo videos for iOS in the github reporitory.
When running CastHelloVideo-ios I see that the program finds the device, conects to the device but it never launches the page. I have the same issue with the other samples in the repository.

The only one that was able to run one time is CastHelloText with Application Id "588BF969". Then I tried to create another application ID "70138F0B" for the same project and it doesn't launch the page, this is the log.

```
2014-02-06 16:46:20.862 HelloTextGoogleCast[8798:60b] device found!! CVC Off
2014-02-06 16:46:20.866 HelloTextGoogleCast[8798:60b] device found!! JBcast
2014-02-06 16:46:22.873 HelloTextGoogleCast[8798:60b] Selecting device:JBcast
2014-02-06 16:46:24.348 HelloTextGoogleCast[8798:60b] connected!!
```

NO LOG LAUNCHING THE PAGE

PLEASE HELP, what can I be doing wrong if is the same URL for both Application ID's, from the same application. AND yes, I replace kReceiverAppID for each case!!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your device for your appId on the developer console? Since the 588BF969 app id works (that is a published app Id, meaning that it is allowed to run on all devices) and your app Id doesn't work, I suspect the issue is in your device registration. Please

(1) Double check the serial number of your device on the developer console to makes sure it matches your device's serial number

(2) Makes sure you have checked the box that sends the serial number to google (this is in the setup application for your chromecast). Also try to connect to http://:9222 from a chrome browser on your network to see if your device is whitelisted

(3) Reboot your chromecast to make sure it has picked up the new configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question and reply to previous reply, non of my applications in the developer console are published yet, and the serial number in the device is fine because it work for one but not for the other one. Also the box that sends the serial number to google was checked.

The problem seems to be some cache, and it is very easy to fix:

1) find device IP on the settings app and got to chrome browser, enter Device IP plus port 9222, and you would see a white page that says "Chromecast Home Screen"

2)Click on "Chromecast Home Screen" and you will see another screen, look for "console" at the top and click on it

3)Finally enter this command: window.location.reload();

Thats it, after doing this, all my apps start working and if I need to change one of the URL address I do this to refresh and load the new URL.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of allowed apps is cached on the device.  When I make changes in the Developer Portal I usually just reboot the device.